# trying to calculate rates runtime using javascript and html5

Tags: javascript

here im trying to calculate rates of bus ticket on selection of seat 
for that i did searched on internet then i found something relavant on stack but its not working

following is html something minor issue help me to get out of this rates are not getting calculate on selection of value

here is my js

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#quantity').change(function(){
      var qty = $('#quantity').val();
      var price = $('#productPrice').val();
      var total = price * qty;
      $("#totalprice").val(total);
    });
    </script>

    <div class="pricesection">
            <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340"/>
        Quantity: 
        <select id="quantity">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    Total: $
    <input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a conflict in some other code that you have not posted (I closed your div, but not much else). Here is a working example that may help you troubleshoot.

```js
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var price = $('#productPrice').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  $('#totalprice').val(total);
});
```

```html
<div class="pricesection">
  <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340" />
  Quantity:
  <select id="quantity">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  Total: $
  <input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() to convert string to number

```
  var qty =parseInt($('#quantity').val());
  var price = parseInt($('#productPrice').val());
  var total = price * qty;
  $("#totalprice").val(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code, but in its' order. The script code goes in your post above the elements inside the document. The running order in WEB is line by line, so when your script asking for $("#quantity") it gets an `undefined` as answer. All you need to do is to move your script to be after your document's elements.

Another solution can be creating of script file and use there with post initialize of the DOM elements- Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ })
```

You can read more here: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

See that the following code is perfect when the script tag is after the elements' initialize:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <div class="pricesection">
            <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="340"/>
        Quantity: 
        <select id="quantity">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    Total: $
    <input type="text" id="totalprice" value="340"/>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#quantity').change(function(){
      var qty = $('#quantity').val();
      var price = $('#productPrice').val();
      var total = price * qty;
      $("#totalprice").val(total);
    });
    </script>
```